# DOM not updating, jquery selectors not detecting dynamic elements for further processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding table into my html using ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/getdata",
  type: "POST",
  data: {data : jsonString},
  success: function( resp ){
          //console.log(resp);
          $('div.table-responsive').html(resp);

  }
  });
```

I am able to get table at right place in broswer view. However when i run in separate script tag

```
console.log("Tables found"+$('table').length)
```

i get 0 in output.

How do I update dom after adding elements dynamically so that i can further process them.

I read many answers on this question, everyone is talking about assigning events to these dynamically added elements however I just need to add some classes to some of these tags so my css and javascript can process them.

Comment: Depends on where you are running the `console.log`

Comment: No i am running it after adding table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table manipulations should be in the callback :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/getdata",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        data: jsonString
    },
    success: function (resp) {
        //console.log(resp);
        $('div.table-responsive').html(resp);
        console.log('table length: ' + $('.table-responsive table').length);
        // Do something with the tables here
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked like charm!!! Thank you so much.. i got my concepts wrong there.. thought javascript wouldn't proceed without completing this ajax request

Comment: Remember to accept the answer, if you think it is the right one ;)

Answer (score -1):

Since this is async, you're gonna need an event or callback. Try something like this:

```
$('table').contentChange( function(){
    // do something
    console.log('table length: '+this.length);
});
```